# ORACLE not showing all records

Tags: oracle

I am having issues with getting the correct number of rows. I ran this code a while back and according to the data, this is the number of rows I should be getting.

**[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPc86.png)**

[image]

But i just ran it again after probably a few weeks and i am sure the data is not messed with because the tables have the same data as before

**[Ran Again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oycLl.png)**

[image]

Comment: The only way you get different result is if the data change. So check again. Are those Tables or Views?

Comment: I rechecked it many times and went through the data myself. and the data was not touched at all. they are tables not views

Comment: How you check? the query are indentical the only explanation is the data change. Or is a view depending of system datetime

Comment: I manually checked the tables and went through the data. I actually created a view before this and thats how I saw that the rows were not similar. I deleted the view and ran the query itself and same thing happened(rows were missing)..

Comment: Please don't post images of your code or links to images, as images are not searchable and this makes it hard to understand your question once the image target gets removed, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374700/why-do-people-post-code-as-images for more information.

Comment: Okay ill keep that in mind next time. thanks

Comment: I saw your data more carefully. There isnt a single row repeat between those both query. So isnt just missing data is a whole new dataset. So your data is definitly changing. The other thing can affect is if `eventsize` is a calculated field. So you can check that.

Comment: Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: You're restricting the eventsize to between 1 and 40. It is possible that the eventsize has grown to > 40 on the 'missing' ones? If you have FLASHBACK enabled, try running the query with the `AS OF TIMESTAMP 
   TO_TIMESTAMP('date time you think the query was OK', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')` to check.